how can I ascertain my TWILIO credentials are correct?
I am making a flask app that users can call a number and then get predetermined responses based on input. I got this number from TWILIO and my SID, auth_token from my TWILIO console. The basic flow is a caller calls the Twilio number, the TWILIO stt engine converts the speech to text then sends that POST request to my flask route ('/ivr) where there's logic on how to handle the input which is then returned as text and twilio converts it to speech and that is what the user hears. However, when I call the number, I am getting code error, when I send a request using POSTMAN I am getting error 401.
I used VSCODE to make my app live by port forwarding and used that link as my webhook url. I also added that link to TWILIO configuration for my phone number. However when I test my app using POSTMAN to send a request, I am getting error 401 unauthorized and upon research found it's because my authentication is wrong or something like that. this is my code snippet. What could the issue be?
#Twilio account credentials 
account_sid= "Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxa"
auth_token = "bxxxxxxxxxxxxxd"

#creating the twilio client 
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

#updating the webhook url for the phone
phone_number_sid = "Pxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0"
webhook_url = "https://9mr9cmz8-8000.inc1.devtunnels.ms/ivr"

phone_number = client.incoming_phone_numbers(phone_number_sid).fetch()
phone_number.update(voice_url=webhook_url, voice_method='POST') 


I'm not really sure what your question is. You mentioned what the app does, that you proxy it, that you use postman and then you show a python script that updates the number config. I would assume you can make this more concise to reproduce the problem. Can you please rephrase and/or remove unnecessary context from the question so it's easier to understand? Generally speaking, a 401 error means your credentials are not correct.

thank you , my authentication token had expired and I had not changed it. finally changed it and now it is working well.
